# Advice for coworker's attitude?

Tags: colleagues

I've recently (in the last 6 months) started a new job that a friend of my told me about. It's an office job for a small local business (<50 employees) and overall, not that complex.

I'm a Software Developer, he's supposed to be Helpdesk/Desktop support. However, they have him doing a lot of work that isn't necessarily in his job description. While I think the descriptions are able to bent a bit in order to fit a dynamic need within the environment, his is vague, even for a Helpdesk position. He believes he should be paid more for working well outside of his job description (doing Security Analyst work instead of Desktop Support).

This all seems pretty standard from what I've seen in other places. My issue, however, is how he is going about the situation. Granted, there's nothing I can do to make him stop and I'm not going to report him for the behavior. But since he's a friend and coworker, how can I advise him in better ways (ethical or however) to go about the situation? He constantly gets upset about requests he normally shouldn't be doing, and he's very open about it. Making passive aggressive jokes that, if I were management, wouldn't let fly even as humor.

How can I give advise to try and help him see the path he's going down is one that's going to get him fired instead of his leaving on his own?

If anything needs more clarification, I'd more than happy to supply it!

Comment: Perhaps getting fired is his goal

Comment: @JoeStrazzere , Not particularly. Though I can see how his comments effect our boss and other coworkers. I'd prefer to say something as to avoid more negative situations

Comment: Has he ever requested a Promotion or higher salary?

Comment: @RealCheeseLord , yes. He's had a meeting with our boss and expressed how he thinks he's not getting paid fairly for doing more work than originally agreed upon (which is normal, in my mind, for a position that is meant to grow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set him down and tell him you get he is frustrated but showing frustration in the manner he is is not going to fix it. Management is not going to react favorably if they hear one of your rants. Settle down and make an objective list of what bothers you and take it to management.